# Rest API node - Parameter in between

Tags: node.js, rest, node-request

I know this is Novice question but couldnt find a best way to do it.

I want to build a rest API with paramater inbetween like

/api/blogs/:blogid/articles/:articleId

I want to route to proper method and identify both blogid and articleid and return response.

Thanks and Best Regards
Moyeen

Answer (score 0):

```
.post('/api/blogs/:blogid/articles/:articleId',
        function(req,res){
       Console.log(req.params.blogid)
       Console.log(req.params.articleId)
       }
```

In this Api ..
Request parameters will give the desired results

Sorry for indentation using mobile app
And do up vote if helpful ... :)

Comment: Which redirection ?? Show me ur code .... To get the response back just do res.status(200).json{};

Comment: in router.js of the yoeman generated structure i have   app.use('/api/articles', require('./api/articles'));                             and in index.js of blogs controller.           
router.get('/:id/articles/:articlesid',controller.articlefetch);